# WCF newbie question

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3

Trying to add a very simple WCF service to my MVC3 project.

Have done the following...

1. Project root -> File -> Add new item -> WCF Service
2. Filled out method details
3. Unit tests for methods all working correctly
4. Browse WCF service -> http://baseUrl/myservicename.svc/mymethodname?myparameter=1234

Currently returning 400's, I know I must be missing something simple but can't see what?

Comment: What **binding** do you use?? By default, a WCF service is a SOAP service - and you cannot just browse to a SOAP endpoint..... you could change your WCF service to REST - use the `webHttpBinding` - or you need to use something like the WCF Test Client tool to get at the service

Comment: But can you at least browse to `http://baseUrl/myservicename.svc` ?? What about `http://baseUrl/myservicename.svc?wsdl` ??

Comment: Yep can browse to the service endpoint, just not to the methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...

Was missing a few web.config sections:

```
<service name="Fully.Qualified.ServiceName">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="Endpoint.Behavior.Name" 
    binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Fully.Qualified.ServiceInterface"></endpoint>
</service>

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Endpoint.Behavior.Name">
        <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

+1 to Marc, think he was on the right track thanks :)

Comment: Because it wasn't THE answer?

Answer (score 1):

What binding do you use??

By default, a WCF service is a SOAP service - and you cannot just browse to a SOAP endpoint...

Please check:

- can you at least browse to `http://baseUrl/myservicename.svc` ??
- what about http://baseUrl/myservicename.svc?wsdl ??

You could change your WCF service to REST - use the `webHttpBinding` - or you need to use something like the [WCF Test Client tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) to get at the service.